# How to configure Apple's podcast app to limit clutter & centralize control in iTunes

Tags: itunes, iphone, podcasts

I would like to know how to set up the Apple podcast app to remove clutter (on the phone) and centralize all controls on the computer's iTunes client. Basically I am trying to replicate the workflow I was using before the podcast app. So I want to :
1) download the podcasts on the computer in the iTunes client
2) transfer the latest 10 episodes on the phone
3) remove from the phone any mention of podcasts that are subscribed but that do not have new content
4) remove from the phone any mention of podcasts that are subscribed but which new content wasn't yet downloaded.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Podcasts synchronization on iTunes is really lame. My suggestion is forget iTunes for that, and manage your podcasts subscriptions only on your iPhone.

Comment: Interesting - I find podcast management infinitely more confusing on the iPhone than on iTunes.